# Expected value of a marginal distribution is a function of $x$?

Tags: probability

> Let $f$ be the joint PDF of the random vector $(X, Y)$.
>
> $f(x, y) = \displaystyle\frac{x(x-y)}{8}$ for $0 < x < 2$ and $-x < y < x$, otherwise it's zero.
>
> Calculate the correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

The problem I'm struggling with here is that to compute the correlation, I need $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $E(XY)$, etc.
I already calculated the $E(X)$, but when trying to calculate $E(Y)$, I get:

$E(Y) = \displaystyle\int_{-x}^xyf_y(y)dy$

Where $f_y(y)$ is the marginal distribution of y, which I computed as:

$f_y(y) = \displaystyle\int_0^2\frac{x(x-y)}{8}dx = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}y$

Because of the limits of integration when computing $E(Y)$, I assumed that the integral was going to be in terms of $x$, and in fact, I computed it and got $E(Y) = -\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{6}$.

Why is my expected value in terms of $x$? Is this the proper way to calculate this? Shouldn't be Y a random variable of it's own?

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct and you even stated the reason why the expectation of $Y$ is in terms of $x$: it is because of the limits of integration. Perhaps it might help to recall the notation from calculus $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. Notice, $F$ is a function of $x$, as $t$ is just a "dummy" variable in $[a,x]$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29  Do not mislead.  The calculations are incorrect, and should be integrating $Y$ over its *full* support of the marginal.  $$\mathsf E(Y)= \int_{-2}^2 (\tfrac 13-\tfrac y4) \mathrm d y$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp you're right. I was thinking conditionally, mistakenly. Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamKemp why is it $E(Y)= \int_{-2}^2 (\tfrac 13-\tfrac y4)dy$  $\ $ and not $E(Y)= \int_{-2}^2 \mathbf y(\tfrac 13-\tfrac y4)dy$? Isn't $E(X)$ usually $\int_{a}^b xf(x)dx$?

Comment: Yes,  Typo there. More, it should be $$\def\abs#1{\lvert #1\rvert} \mathsf E(Y)=\int_{-2}^2 y\cdot\tfrac 1{48}(-2 \abs{y}^3 + 3 y \abs{y}^2 - 12 y + 16)~\mathsf d y $$   See my full answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, indeed the expectation of $Y$ should *not* be a function over $X$ (nor over $x$).   It shall be a constant.

Be careful.   You are using the support for the *conditional* pdf for $Y$ given $X=x$, not that for the *marginal* pdf for $Y$.

Examine the support for the *joint* pdf:

Because $\{(x,y): 0\leqslant x\leqslant 2, -x\leqslant y\leqslant x\}=\{(x,y):-2\leqslant y\leqslant 2, \lvert y\rvert\leqslant x\leqslant 2\}$

Therefore, by Fubini's Theorem : $\quad\displaystyle\int_0^2 \int_{-x}^x f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x ~=~ \int_{-2}^2\int_{\lvert y\rvert}^2 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y $

And here the inner integrals represent the marginal pdf for the relevant random variable, and the bound on the outer integrals cover their support.

So we have: $\displaystyle f_X(x) ~{= \mathbf 1_{(0\leqslant x\leqslant 2)} \int_{-x}^x \tfrac{x(x-y)}8\mathrm d y \\ = \tfrac 14{x^3} \mathbf 1_{(0\leqslant x\leqslant 2)}}\\ \displaystyle f_Y(y) ~{= \mathbf 1_{(-2\leqslant y\leqslant 2)}\int_{\lvert y\rvert}^2 \tfrac{x(x-y)}8\mathrm d x \\ = \tfrac 1{48} (- 2 \lvert y\rvert^3 + 3 y^3 - 12 y + 16)\mathbf 1_{(-2\leqslant y\leqslant 2)}}$

And hence: $\displaystyle \mathsf E(Y) = \int_{-2}^2 y\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y\\ \displaystyle \mathsf E(X) = \int_0^2 x\,f_X(x)\mathrm d x$

---

Although it mayhap be easier to avoid the absolute values and use: $$\mathsf E(Y)=\int_0^2 \int_{-x}^x y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x \\ \mathsf E(X)=\int_0^2 x \int_{-x}^x f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x \\ \mathsf E(XY)=\int_0^2 x\int_{-x}^x y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that we can calculate $E(Y)$ directly from the original joint density function, without the use of marginal density functions.

$$\int_0^2 \int_{-x}^x y \cdot f(x,y) \text{ }dy \text{ } dx  $$

This will eliminate any $x$ terms in the final answer of $E(Y)$.